# Angular multiple services in one component

Tags: angular

Welcome to the latest edition of An Angular Newbie Asks a Stupid Question!

I have an In-Memory-Data-Service set up in lieu of connecting my web services. I have two arrays, Users and UserData, defined in the In-Memory-Data-Service. I don't know how to use both in the same component html template.

In the Src directory I have a service.ts set up for both but I still can't figure out how to use both in the same component.

Comment: Your question is unclear, can you show some code?

Comment: please read angular docs.

Comment: import the two services in the component via `import { MyService1 } from './path/to/service1.ts` and  `import { MyService2 } from './path/to/service2.ts` and then declare an instance of them in the component constructor like: `constructor(private myService1: Service1, private myService1: Service1) {}`. Then use them like `myService1.myFunction1()` etc...

Comment: is it a good practice to inject and use multiple services in a single component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your code is, I'm providing a noob level example for a simple service

**//Service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service {

  private users=['a','b','c'];
  private userData=['x','y','z'];

  constructor() { }

  getUsers():<any>
  {
    return this.users;
  }

  getUserData():<any>
  {
    return this.userData;
  }


}
```

**//Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Service } from '../Service.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account-detail',
  templateUrl: './account-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account-detail.component.css']
})
export class AccountDetailComponent implements OnInit {

 public userArr,userDataArr;
  constructor(private service:Service) { }

  ngOnInit() {





    this.userArr= this.service.getUsers();
    this.usersDataArr = this.service.getUserData();




  }

}
```

Answer (score 13):

To use one or more service(s) in your component you will need to Import that service in that component like

```
import { MyService1 } from '../services/MyService1.service';
import { MyService2 } from '../services/MyService2.service';
```

then you need to inject these service in constructor

```
constructor(private myService1: MyService1, private myService2: MyService2) { }
```